Flatband with our Moire Physics
Is there any material Class available where the lattice vectors are in the order of several nm instead of Angstrom? I am looking for some exotic not well studies lattice class which can be experimentally fabricable.

I don't understand the connection between the title and the body of the question. Are you just asking for systems with large lattice constants as in the text, or something more specific?

If you want a big lattice, crystalize a big molecule. Introduction to protein crystallization

Optical lattices are typically on the order of $\mathrm{\mu m}$ if that is of any help

I am currently looking for a real material class which can form moire potentials inside bulk crystals .
